# Maximum Singular Value of $(A \cos\phi+B \sin\phi) \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, tensor-decomposition, singular-values

**Problem**

I am wondering if there is a way to efficiently compute the maximum singular value of 
\begin{align}
C(\phi)=A \cos\phi+B \sin\phi,
\end{align}
where A, B and C are real 2x2 matrices.

**Numerical Approach** (edited)

So far, I could only solve the problem 'numerically' by

- Direct optimization (e.g. using matlabs's `fmincon`), which is sensitive to the choice of the intial value of $\phi$. Other (global) optimizers are more reliable but need far more evaluations. Maybe an appropriate bisection algorithm would help here? Suggestions?
- Rank-1 tensor approximation (e.g. using 'tenser toolbox' for matlab), which also needs quite some iterations. I am not very familiar with tensor algebra so I am not sure if this approach is even valid in general.

**Notes** (edited)

- It can be assumed that either $A$ or $B$ is positive semidefinite.
- QZ-decompositon may be applied to make $A$ and $B$ (and thus also $C$) triangular. But I am not sure if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the special case of $\phi=\pi/4$, you're essentially asking for the maximum singular value of $A+B$. So without further structural assumptions imposed on $A$ and $B$, the question is basically unanswerable, as the eigenvalues of $A+B$ can basically be anything within the spectrum of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If it helps, it can be assumed that either A or B is positive semidefinite. Furthermore, QZ-decompositon may be applied to make A and B (and thus also C) triangular . 

So far, I could solve the problem numerically by
a) direct optimization (e.g. using matlabs's `fmincon`) which is sensitive to the choice of the intial value of $\phi$. Other (global) optimizers are more reliable but need far more evaluations. An appropriate bisection method may help?! OR
b) rank-1 tensor approximation (e.g. using tenser toolbox for matlab), which also needs quite some iterations.

Comment: The additional constraint makes no difference. You can easily come up with $A$ and $B$ that satisfy all your assumptions, yet $A+B$ can be literally anything.